# Edit of arrows in diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you please help me to edit the arrows in my diagram? Consider the following `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=2em,minimum width=2em]
  {
(0,0)&(0,1)&(0,2)&(0,3)&\dots&&(0,q) \\
(1,0)&(1,1)&(1,2)&\dots&&(1,1-q)\\
(2,0)&(2,1)&\dots&&\iddots\\
(3,0)&\dots \\
\vdots&(q-1,1)\\(q,0)\\};
 \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1)
    (m-2-1) edge (m-1-2)
    (m-1-2) edge (m-3-1)
    (m-3-1) edge (m-2-2)
    (m-2-2) edge (m-1-3)
    (m-1-3) edge (m-4-1)
    (m-4-1) edge (m-3-2)
    (m-3-2)edge (m-2-3)
    (m-2-3)edge (m-1-4)
    (m-6-1) edge (m-5-2) 
    (m-5-2) edge (m-3-5)
    (m-3-5) edge (m-2-6)
    (m-2-6) edge (m-1-7)
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the lines are not aligned.

Comment: The arrows are not organized

Answer (score 5):

With one more row and `tikzcd`, the arrows will be parallel.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep={4.5em,between origins}]
(0,0) \arrow[d] & (0,1) \arrow[ddl] & (0,2) \arrow[dddll] & (0,3) & \dots & \dots & (0,q) \\
(1,0) \arrow[ur] & (1,1) \arrow[ur] & (1,2) \arrow[ur] & \dots & & (1,1-q) \arrow[ur] \\
(2,0) \arrow[ur] & (2,1) \arrow[ur] & \dots & & \iddots \arrow[ur] \\
(3,0) \arrow[ur] & \dots \\
\vdots \\
\vdots & (q-1,1) \arrow[uuurrr] \\
(q,0) \arrow[ur] 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much,I greatly appreciate it.